# Angular 2 - How can I pre-populate 3 formgroups on init

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the below code which allows a user to add a new set of fields. But I want the component to render out 3 sets of data on init.

At the moment one set of fields is made via the initRateRow function but how can I make it loop through an httpservice to push it into the "this._fb.group"?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-exchange-rates',
  templateUrl: './exchange-rates.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./exchange-rates.component.scss']
})
export class ExchangeRatesComponent implements OnInit {

    public myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            rates: this._fb.array([
                this.initRateRow(),
            ])
        });
    }

    initRateRow() {
        return this._fb.group({
            rateUnit: ['24', Validators.required],
            currencyFrom: ['GBP', Validators.required],
            currencyTo: ['USD', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    blankRateRow() {
        return this._fb.group({
            rateUnit: ['', Validators.required],
            currencyFrom: ['', Validators.required],
            currencyTo: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    addRateRow() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['rates'];
        control.push(this.blankRateRow());
    }

    removeRateRow(i: number) {
        const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['rates'];
        control.removeAt(i);
    }

    save(model) {
        // call API to save
        // ...
        console.log(model);
    }

}
```

Comment: why you need httpservice for this you just want to render them on start ?

Comment: Hi @BabarBilal, I need to render the actual data from a database that's why I need to use the httpservice.

Comment: @BabarBilal But it would still need to be done on init :)

Comment: I think you should call http service in constructor it'll be executed before ngOnInit() or you can call it in parent component constructor store result in variable and put it for input for this component you will git that in ngOnInit()

Comment: Have you thought about using a route guard?

Comment: my answer helps?

Comment: Yes that worked great thanks @JohnSiu sorry for the delay in replying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in `ngOnInit()`.

```
ngOnInit(){
    let url = '/getData'; // API url
    this.http.get(url)
        // Assuming data arrive as json
        .map(r => r.json())
        // Assuming data arrive as array of row
        .subscribe(rowArray => rowArray.forEach(row => {

            // Use `row` to init 1 row

        }));
}
```